# MYSQL set timezone in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

How can I change MYSQL TIMEZONE to GMT format like this function in PHP:
/*SET GMT TIMEZONE*/
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');

My DB class is here:

```
class DB {
    private static $instance;
    private $MySQLi;

    private function __construct(array $dbOptions){

        $this->MySQLi = @ new mysqli(   $dbOptions['db_host'],
                                        $dbOptions['db_user'],
                                        $dbOptions['db_pass'],
                                        $dbOptions['db_name'] );

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception('Database error.');
        }

        $this->MySQLi->set_charset("utf8");
    }

    public static function init(array $dbOptions){
        if(self::$instance instanceof self){
            return false;
        }

        self::$instance = new self($dbOptions);
    }

    public static function getMySQLiObject(){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi;
    }

    public static function query($q){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi->query($q);
    }

    public static function prepare($q){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi->prepare($q);
    }

    public static function esc($str){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($str));
    }

}
```

And my queries like this in other files:

```
DB::query('UPDATE `calendar_data` SET `data` = "'.DB::esc(json_encode($array)).'", `upcoming_time` = "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $upcoming).'", `time_now` = NOW() WHERE `id` = "1"');
```

Where should I insert my query to the class for run it once?

Thanks!

```
$this->MySQLi->set_charset("utf8");
$this->MySQLi->query("SET timezone = 'GMT'");
```

- Doesn't work. If I use NOW(), server time was inserted (GMT-4). Where is a problem???

Comment: I would strongly recommend _against_ suppressing your errors using the `@` character.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
$this->MySQLi->query("SET time_zone = '+0:00'");
```

Using named timezones will only work if the time zone information tables in the MySQL database have been created and populated.

Answer (score 6):

After you write this:

```
$this->MySQLi->set_charset("utf8");
```

Also write this:

```
$this->MySQLi->query("SET timezone = 'GMT'");
```

This timezone setting will apply to all future queries sent on that connection.

Also, ensure you've set up the zone tables in the mysql database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use NOW(), server time was inserted (GMT-4). Where is a problem???

Comment: Did you run `SET timezone` again before you `SELECT`ed the date back out to check what was inserted? If you connect with the `mysql` CLI and run a query it's going to use the server time zone again.

Comment: set timezone was placed to the script before my INSERT query. I i'm tried to run this query: DB::query('UPDATE `users_calendar_data` SET `data` = "'.DB::esc(json_encode($array)).'", `upcoming_time` = "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $upcoming).'", `time_now` = NOW() WHERE `id` = "1"'); But my time_now value is equal to the server time (not GMT).

Comment: If you think it's in the wrong time zone, that means you must be `SELECT`ing it somewhere look at what you `UPDATE`d. Are you setting the time zone on THAT connection? Also, did you populate the MySQL tzinfo database? You can't do any of this without that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation the variable is named "time_zone" not "timezone".

Answer (score 4):

From manual;

> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:

```
mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
```

So must be like this;

```
$this->MySQLi->query("SET time_zone = 'GMT'");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has extensive [timezone support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html). You can set it on server level, on a per connection basis and even per query. I think executing 'SET time_zone = xxx' in __construct is enough for you.