# How to adjust timestamp within sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have a query:

```
$time = time();
$query = "SELECT timestamp FROM sales WHERE timestamp < '$time'";
```

=

The timestamp (in seconds, i.e. 1554901254) in that DB is 4 hours ahead of `time()`. Is there a way to adjust that timestamp within the query? I know something like `$time = time()+14400` should work, but can I adjust timestamp itself to let's say `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear! In case you are looking to make MySQL aware of your timezone, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296780/mysql-set-timezone-in-php-code

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that,

```
 where timestamp < date_add($time, INTERVAL 4 hour)
```

Documentation for [date_add](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($yourTimestamp);
echo $datetime->getTimezone()->getName();
echo $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

This should do the trick for you.